How can i concatenate two table field to be display as one field in the jquery Data table?
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $('#data-grid-branch_infos').DataTable({
        bProcessing: true,
        bServerSide: true,
        sAjaxSource: 'GetBranchPaginatedList',
        "fnServerParams": function (aoData) {
            //aoData.push({ "name": "dstatus", "value": $('#ShowClosed').val() });
        },
        "aoColumns": [
            { "mData": 'row_no', name: "row_no", title: 'SNo.', width: 20, filterable: false },
            { "mData": 'is_corporate', name: "is_corporate", title: "Is Corporate", width: 150 },
            { "mData": 'parent_id', name: "parent_id", title: "Parent Id", width: 150 },
            { "mData": 'br_alias', name: "br_alias", title: "Branch Alias", width: 150 },
            { "mData": 'full_name', name: "full_name", title: "Full Name", width: 150 },
            { "mData": 'full_name_locale', name: "full_name_locale", title: "Full Name Locale", 
        ]
    });

Due to the limitation of field i further cannot add more field which i have to added now i want to concatenate the field that have suffix as "locale" with their not suffix field for example i want to concatenate the full_name and full_name_locale field data and should display in the one column of field so that i can add others field i know this is done by using render function but i am stuck how to add render function in this ?
I tried to concatenate table two field which have suffix "locale" with their non suffix field just like full_name and full_name_locale and i wanted to display these two field data in one table so how can i acheive it using render function in Jquery Data Table?

I want to know that whether you could render the data table in the website successfully or not? If yes, then I trust you have been already able to get the value of full_name and full_name_locale. Can we use the column render method to combine these 2 fields together? By the way, if we are able to change the data source, shall we try to re-format the API response in the server side which might create a new property with value combining 2 fields together?
